# Write-Host prints entire object instead of one property of it when surrounded by quotes

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

```
$AllDrivesExceptBootDrive = Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne 'C'} | Select-Object DriveLetter, AllocationUnitSize

foreach ($d in $AllDrivesExceptBootDrive)
{
    Write-Host "Checking Drive $d.DriveLetter"
}
```

Prints:

```
Checking Drive @{DriveLetter=F; AllocationUnitSize=4096}.DriveLetter
Checking Drive @{DriveLetter=G; AllocationUnitSize=4096}.DriveLetter
Checking Drive @{DriveLetter=E; AllocationUnitSize=4096}.DriveLetter
Checking Drive @{DriveLetter=H; AllocationUnitSize=4096}.DriveLetter
Checking Drive @{DriveLetter=I; AllocationUnitSize=4096}.DriveLetter
```

How do I keep quotes around `Write-Host` and still print it as below?

```
Checking Drive F
Checking Drive G
Checking Drive E
Checking Drive H
Checking Drive I
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the `about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules):

> Only simple variable references can be directly embedded in an expandable string. Variables references using array indexing **or member access must be enclosed in a subexpression**.

Change the string literal to surround the expression with the subexpression operator `$()`, like this:

```
Write-Host "Checking Drive $($d.DriveLetter)"
```